# On display of hidden element it shows on wrong place because of scroll, only in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't realy know how to explain this thing in short sentence.
I don't know if it is bug or not..

In parent div with fixed height and overflow-y scroll, I have multiple children elements, which has jquery function click, what displays hidden element in these divs. When I scroll down to last div, after click, hidden element displays in wrong place.

I tried to search for this problem, cause it should be pretty common. But nothing came up.s

It's realy hard to explain with words. Just look at this jquery example with mozilla and after that with chrome.
https://jsfiddle.net/zvwcdzjz/2/#

**P.S. I need my original example work and look exactly the same on chrome and mozilla, cause right now on mozilla everything looks exactly as i want it to be, but it bugs on chrome.**
It can  be solved with jQuery too, makes no difference for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="el">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="blocktoopen"></div>
      <div class="button">click to open</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="blocktoopen"></div>
      <div class="button">click to open</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="blocktoopen"></div>
      <div class="button">click to open</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#el {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#el .content {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 90px;
  float: left;
}
.blocktoopen {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".block").children(".blocktoopen").show();
  });
  $("#el").scroll(function(){
     $(".blocktoopen").hide(); });
});
```

Comment: And what is the desired result?

Comment: The expected result should be that the last block on the bottom of the scroll should appear in the same location like the ones before it. In chrome it's way too low. In Firefox it looks just fine.

Comment: Like ketchup said, when scrolled all the way to bottom, and click on last block, red box appears in wrong place.

Comment: How can i bump my question?

Answer (score 1):

The set height of #el was causing the red box to appear in the incorrect location. I have removed this. See the example below:

Change:

```
#el {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

To:

```
#el {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

And then you're good to go.

Comment: Of course it can be solved like that. But i have limited place in my website. I need height to be limited, and use scrolling to see more elements.

Answer (score 0):

To make your life simpler make the parent .bloc relative so the blocktoopen will be computed relatively. Will help with the responsiveness.

```
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
position: relative; 
}

.blocktoopen {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
bottom: 50%;  
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
 right: 0;
}
```

Comment: When I change parent to position: relative, then overflowing .blocktoopen is not visible. But in my website i have it overflowing so it won't work this time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comment so here is another try with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yasinyaqoobi/qc1wzjpq/1/). I am not sure if you have horizontal scroll as well. remove margin-right from .blocktoopen and add right:0; Also wrap all your internal content inside a div and set the width to maybe 225px

```
#el {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#el .content {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position: relative; 
}
.button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 90px;
  float: left;
}
.blocktoopen {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  top: 50%; 
  bottom: 50%; 
  right: 0;
}

.internal{
  width: 225px;
  }
```

Comment: .blocktoopen must be on outside not inside.

Comment: blocktoopen is inside .block already. This is to set you on the the right track. You can tweak it to match your situation.

Comment: What im trying to do is: When i click on parent, what is located inside div with overflow-y scroll, make appear box on outside of this parent AND the div with overflow-y scroll(.boxtoopen, parents , parent). What you did: Made some kind of internal element in .block , with text, what makes no difference, and changed blocktoopen style so it doesn't do anything i want, even in mozilla(It does not appear, because it gets affected by overflow:hidden on #el). If you dont get something, open my original jsfiddle again in mozilla and then in chrome. (scroll it down and click on last button)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to click on 2 buttons without scrolling? Try it. Looks like you were using `visibility: hidden;` and not `display: none;`. Maybe trying to set the `position: relative;` ...

Just seen the jquery script. `Show()` and `hide()` appears to work as `visibility` css property.
If u look with Chrome DevTools the jsFiddle example you will see that you can't see the red boxes but they are still there.